# Read project setting in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, mvc, asp.net-mvc

I have a Table that I store All `setting` in that , it is like below :

```
public  class Setting:IEntity
{
    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a service like this to update and read `Setting` Table :

```
   public class SettingService : ISettingService
{

    #region Fields

    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;
    private readonly IDbSet<Setting> _settings;

    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> _cash = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, object>();

    #endregion

    #region Methods


    #region ctor

    public SettingService(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
        _settings = _uow.Set<Setting>();
        if (_cash.IsEmpty)
            lock (_cash)
            {
                if (_cash.IsEmpty)
                    _settings.ToList().ForEach(item => _cash.TryAdd(item.Key, item.Value));
            }
    }

    #endregion

    public T Get<T>() where T : ISetting
    {
        object value;
        var setting = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
        var prefix = typeof(T).Name;

        foreach (PropertyInfo item in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {
            string key = $"{prefix}.{item.Name}";

            _cash.TryGetValue(key, out value);
            if (item.PropertyType == typeof(Boolean))
            {
                bool result;
                Boolean.TryParse(value?.ToString(), out result);
                item.SetValue(setting, result);
            }
            else
                item.SetValue(setting, value);
        }
        return setting;
    }

    public void Set<T>(T model) where T : ISetting
    {
        var prefix = typeof(T).Name;
        Type type = typeof(T);

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in typeof(T).GetProperties())
        {

            var key = $"{prefix}.{prop.Name}";
            var setting = _settings.FirstOrDefault(row => row.Key == key);
            var isAddedd = true;
            if (setting == null)
            {
                setting = new Setting { Key = key };
                _settings.Add(setting);
                _uow.MarkAsAdded(setting);
                isAddedd = false;
            }

            setting.Value = prop.GetValue(model, null)?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
            if (isAddedd)
                _uow.MarkAsChanged(setting);
            _cash.AddOrUpdate(key, setting.Value, (oldkey, oldValue) => setting.Value);
        }

    }

    #endregion
}
```

I use this Service Like below :

```
var data = _settingService.Get<AboutSetting>(); // when I want to featch from db
     _settingService.Set<AboutSetting>(aboutUsViewModel);// for update
```

now I need to Read All `Project Setting` from project , in some Views I need just some of them like `Address , Tel ,...`

I have created some Classes Like below :

```
public static class CompanyConfig
{
    private static CompanyInformationSetting _companySettings;
    private static ISettingService _settingService;

    static CompanyConfig()
    {
        _settingService = ApplicationObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<ISettingService>();
        _companySettings = _settingService.Get<CompanyInformationSetting>();

    }

    public static string CompanyAddress
    {
        get { return _companySettings.Address; }
    }
}
```

and use them in View Like :

```
 <h2> Address : @(CompanyConfig.CompanyAddress) </h2>
```

**Is there a way better than this , does this way bad for Performance ?**

Another Way is to change `BaseViewPage` Like below and set some properties like below :

```
public class BaseViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    private readonly ISettingService _settingService;
    public BaseViewPage()
    {
        _settingService = ApplicationObjectFactory.Container.GetInstance<ISettingService>();
    }

    public override void Execute()
    {
    }

    public string CompanyName
    {
        get { return _settingService.Get<CompanyInformationSetting>("CompanyName"); }
    }

    public string CompanyPhoneNumber
    {
        get { return _settingService.Get<CompanyInformationSetting>("PhoneNumber"); }
    }
    public string CompanyEmail
    {
        get { return _settingService.Get<CompanyInformationSetting>("Email"); }
    }
    public string CompanyAddress
    {
        get { return _settingService.Get<CompanyInformationSetting>("Address"); }
    }

}
```

in this way we dont need to static class and it solves singleton of `UnitOfwork`

Comment: updated post , I've add another way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick note first, `_cash` should be `_cache` [dictionary definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cache):

> a temporary storage space or memory that allows fast access to data

Is this bad for performance?

You'd have to measure it but you've got a non-trivial amount of reflection on every call to `Get` and `Set`. Why not serialize your values to JSON or Xml to store in the database? Create an interface and you can decide on your implementation later. You could test a bunch of serializers and see which is fastest.

```
public interface ISettingSerializer
{
    string Serialize<T>(T value);
    T Deserialize<T>(string value);
}
```

What I'm really trying to say is: don't create your own serialization. There are already multiple good options that support a lot of configuration. E.g. think about attributes to control how or even whether a member is included.

---

You have another problem - a [captive dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).

You have a **Singleton** `CompanyConfig` (as it's static) that holds a reference to a unit of work (through the settings service) which shouldn't be kept alive for the lifetime of the application IMO.

Comment: thank you . I've got another Idea , to put `Setting.josn ` file in `Project Root` and when `project `start at first read settings from `database ` and put them in `json` file .

Comment: updated post , I've add another way

Comment: @workquestion - I've done similar to your update in the past and think it's a good way to go.